# udf created time series having trouble writing to parquet

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have the pyspark code below.  In it I'm filling missing end_date values in a dataframe tz_inventory_aud_df2 with a date far in the future.  I get the minimum start_date from the same dataframe.  Then I create a time series for every date from the minimum start_date to the current date.  I use a udf to create a dataframe with those dates, and then left join from that dataframe to the tz_inventory_aud_df to get a sum of fields filtered by each of the dates in the dataframe I created.  When I try to finally write the dataframe out as parquet files I'm getting the error below in my driver log.  Does anyone know what is causing the error, and can you suggest how to fix it?

code:

```
tz_inventory_aud_df2=tz_inventory_aud_df.fillna({'end_date':'3018-01-01 00:00:00'})



        bs_df=tz_inventory_aud_df.agg({'start_date':'min'})\
        .withColumn('min_date',to_date(col('min(start_date)')))


        timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


        bs_df = bs_df.withColumn('current_date',to_date(unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("timestamp")))

        # creating time-series dataframe



        # UDF
        def generate_date_series(start, stop):
            return [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]

        # Register UDF for later usage
        spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(DateType()) )

        # mydf is a DataFrame with columns `start` and `stop` of type DateType()
        bs_df.createOrReplaceTempView("mydf")

        filldate_df=spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(min_date, current_date)) as dates FROM mydf")

        daily_af_units=filldate_df.alias('a').join(tz_inventory_aud_df2.alias('b'),
             (col('b.current_flag')==1)
              &(col('a.dates')>=col('b.start_date'))
              &(col('a.dates')<col('b.end_date')),
              how='inner'
             )\
        .select(col('b.product_id'),
               col('a.dates'),
               (col('b.available_units')+col('b.reserved_units')+col('b.packed_and_ready_units')).alias('daily_product_remaining')
               )\
        .alias('c')\
        .groupby(['product_id','dates']).sum()




        daily_af_units=daily_af_units.withColumn("daily_product_remaining",daily_af_units["sum(daily_product_remaining)"])

        daily_af_units=daily_af_units[['product_id', 'dates', 'daily_product_remaining']]


daily_af_units.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(bckt_pth1+'daily_units_remaining')
```

error:

```
2020-03-17 08:03:05,437 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 0.1 in stage 12651.0 (TID 479153, ip-10-100-7-60.glue.dnsmasq, executor 7): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1584428038308_0005/container_1584428038308_0005_01_000013/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1584428038308_0005/container_1584428038308_0005_01_000013/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1584428038308_0005/container_1584428038308_0005_01_000013/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1584428038308_0005/container_1584428038308_0005_01_000013/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: toInternal(f(*a))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1584428038308_0005/container_1584428038308_0005_01_000013/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "script_2020-03-17-06-55-38.py", line 1839, in generate_date_series
    return [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
```

Update:

```
tz_inventory_aud_df2=tz_inventory_aud_df[tz_inventory_aud_df['current_flag']==1]\
        .fillna({'end_date':'3018-01-01 00:00:00',
                  'start_date':'1990-01-01 00:00:00'})



        bs_df=tz_inventory_aud_df2.agg({'start_date':'min'})\
        .withColumn('min_date',to_date(col('min(start_date)')))

        timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        bs_df = bs_df.withColumn('current_date',to_date(unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("timestamp")))

        # creating time-series dataframe


        # UDF
        def generate_date_series(start, stop):
            return [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]

        # Register UDF for later usage
        spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(DateType()) )

        # mydf is a DataFrame with columns `start` and `stop` of type DateType()
        bs_df.createOrReplaceTempView("mydf")

        filldate_df=spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(min_date, current_date)) as dates FROM mydf")

        daily_af_units=filldate_df.alias('a').join(tz_inventory_aud_df2.alias('b'),
             (col('b.current_flag')==1)
              &(col('a.dates')>=col('b.start_date'))
              &(col('a.dates')<col('b.end_date')),
              how='inner'
             )\
        .select(col('b.product_id'),
               col('a.dates'),
               (col('b.available_units')+col('b.reserved_units')+col('b.packed_and_ready_units')).alias('daily_product_remaining')
               )\
        .alias('c')\
        .groupby(['product_id','dates']).sum()




        daily_af_units=daily_af_units.withColumn("daily_product_remaining",daily_af_units["sum(daily_product_remaining)"])

        daily_af_units=daily_af_units[['product_id', 'dates', 'daily_product_remaining']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem does not occur due to write operation** (remember that spark is based on lazy computation) but rather due to this operation :

```
from datetime import date
import time
date.fromtimestamp(time.time()) - None

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-059d3edeb205> in <module>
      1 from datetime import date
      2 import time
----> 3 date.fromtimestamp(time.time()) - None

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'
```

This happens while executing your udf certainly **caused by null values** appearing in your dataframe at some point.

Looking at your code is that in you tried but to remove null value at the first line. But then at the second line **you didn't use the resulting dataframe**... I am not sure this is the intended behaviour. So change your first lines with :

```
tz_inventory_aud_df2=tz_inventory_aud_df.fillna({'end_date':'3018-01-01 00:00:00'})


bs_df=tz_inventory_aud_df2.agg({'start_date':'min'})\
        .withColumn('min_date',to_date(col('min(start_date)')))
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.  I've added the update above where I'm using the correct version of the dataframe later in my code.  I also tried to fill any null 'start_date' so the udf wouldn't have issues.  But I'm still getting the same error when trying to write.  Is there something I'm not understanding?  The error is caused by nulls in start_date right?